# Can not resolve Vite html loader file error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, node-modules, vite

I am using vite for a project, but when I run `npm run dev` I get the error
 `Failed to scan for dependencies from entries: <path>/Learning/Vite-test/index.html`

`[ERROR] No loader is configured for ".html" files: index.html`

I do not know what may be causing the error (and it seems either new or specific to my case) as I am still learning and do not seem to find any issue related through search.

I tried installing `html loader` and adding it to the vite configuration file but it did not change anything.

The following is my vite configuration file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json', '.html'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: 'html-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  }
})
```

I also get a similar error when creating projects with Vue/cli which is:

```
Compiling...


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                8:24:19 PM
 error 

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<path>\learn-vuetify\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.8.106&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '<path>\learn-vuetify'

ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<path>\learn-vuetify\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.8.106&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '<path>\learn-vuetify'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I have some ideas in mind:

1. Related and caused by some local security option in windows
2. Something went wrong when installing node
3. Corrupt dependencies (someone could have had the same error, but no one did - rare).

I have no idea for the cause ... please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online ?

Comment: Do you mean the docs or the online environment?

The problem is raised just after running : `npm init vue@latest` so there is no issue with the code.

I also get a similar error when starting the project with vue cli, so I suspect they may be related or the issue is local but I have no idea what it can be??

Comment: I did not find anything in the docs (to my experience). 
kindly check the edited question.

Comment: @RoarS. please check the edited question if you have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered same error and the problem was with the path
My Path was:

```
E:\#Development\MERN\R\First-app
```

This `#` in the path was causing the issue.

well it works fine for me now.

New Path:

```
E:\Development\MERN\R\First-app
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was local as expected!!
It was that the path was too long and containing spaces, so instead of using:

```
D:/folder/sub folder/ 1 sub folder/ another_subfolder/some-more/myProject
```

Use:

```
D:/folder/sub_folder/myProject
```

Good Luck everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. I had to uninstall the anti-virus(Smadav) on my computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).